# reference binding error to misaligned address

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I was solving a question on leet in which I tried to recursion with stacks.
But during the execution

`runtime error: reference binding to misaligned address 0xbebebebebebec0ba for type 'int', which requires 4 byte alignment (stl_deque.h) 0xbebebebebebec0ba: note: pointer points here <memory cannot be printed> SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_deque.h:180:16`

I dont understand that it is because of the recursion or something about a memory problem.

> https://leetcode.com/problems/daily-temperatures/description/
> this was the question.

```
class Solution
{
public:
    vector<int> dailyTemperatures(vector<int> &temp)
    {
        vector<int> dp;

        for (int i = temp.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            check(i, temp, dp);
        }

        return dp;
    }

    void check(int i, vector<int> &temp, vector<int> &dp)
    {
        stack<int> st;
        if (temp[i] > temp[st.top()])
        {
            if (st.empty())
            {
                dp[i] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                st.pop();
                check(i, temp, dp);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            dp[i] = st.top() - i;
            st.push(i);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a memory problem. You have undefined behaviour right here

```
    stack<int> st;
    if (temp[i] > temp[st.top()])
```

Stack `st` is empty but you are trying to retrieve the top element.

Not sure what the solution is as all paths though your code seem to try to access the top element of the stack.

There is also a problem with vector `dp`, it is empty, it never gets any elements added to it, but you try to assign to it with `dp[i] =`  in a couple of places. So that's another memory problem.