# Runtime error : std::pair<int, int>', which requires 4 byte alignment (stl_deque.h)

Tags: c++, memory, stack, runtime

I am not able to understand why i am getting an error that says

Line 172: Char 16: runtime error: reference binding to misaligned address 0xbebebebebebec0b6 for type 'std::pair<int, int>', which requires 4 byte alignment (stl_deque.h)
0xbebebebebebec0b6: note: pointer points here

SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11/bits/stl_deque.h:181:16

Please help.

```
class Solution
{
public:
  int sumSubarrayMins(vector<int> &arr)
  {
    stack<pair<int, int>> st;
    st.push({0, arr[0]});
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
      if (st.top().second < arr[i])
      {
        sum += st.top().second * (i - (st.top().first));
        st.push({i, arr[i]});
      }
      else
      {
        while (!st.empty() && st.top().second > arr[i])
        {
          sum += arr[i] * (i - (st.top().first));
          st.pop();
        }
      }
    }
    return sum;
  }
};
```

I tried creating a stack of pairs but it didn't worked out

Comment: Always make sure that the stack is not empty before accessing its top. Your `while` loop could empty the whole stack, which is bad when you then do `if (st.top().second < arr[i])`

Comment: That error generally means you are accessing something uninitialized or out of bounds, like the top of an empty stack. It would be helpful if you put together a [mcve] with a test case that shows the issue. Stepping through the code with a debugger would probably help you find it yourself.

Comment: See [reference binding error stack to misaligned address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74844258/reference-binding-error-to-misaligned-address)

Comment: What input are you giving it when you get the runtime error?